# Ошибка при обьявление массива

Tags: python, массивы

Пишу бота для ВК на python, но я не очень силён в синтаксисе.
Я написал код, но он не хочет работать ))
У меня есть документ, в котором есть сообщения и ответы на них (они разделяются знаком '\').
Нужно, чтобы скрипт открывал этот документ и каждую строчку добавлял в массив1.

Новое сообщение бота ВК поступает в отдельную функцию.
Перед этим я обьявляю массив2
При новом сообщение скрипт должен пройтись по массиву1, извлечь весь текст каждого элемента массива до знака-разделителя('\').
И сделать проверку: if извлеченный текст in новое сообщение:
Извлечь весь текст этого же элемента массива, но после знака-разделителя('\') и добавить этот текст в массив2
После этого нужно выбрать рандомный элемент из массива2 и отправить его в ВК.
Над отправкой в ВК можете не париться, это уже готово.

```py
f = open('answer_databse.txt', 'r')

om = 0
omg = []

for line in f:
    om = om + 1
    omg[om] = line

def onNewMsg(text,user):
    ddd = {}
    dada = 0
    for item in omg:
        result = re.match(r'(.+)\\', item)
        if result in text:
            dada = dada + 1
            ddd[dada] = re.match(r'\\(.+)', item)
    ada = 0
    for item in ddd:
        ada = ada + 1
    txt = ddd[random.uniform(1, ada)]
    write_msg(user,txt,random.uniform(10300130, 20300130))
    return
```

---

Вот другой вариант этого же кода. Но всё равно какая-то ошибка при прохождение по строчкам документа. imgur.com/yjLLllH

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и покажите ваш код для начала.

Comment: `f = open('answer_databse.txt', 'r')

om = 0
omg = []

for line in f:
 om = om + 1
 omg[om] = line

def onNewMsg(text,user):
 ddd = {}
 dada = 0
 for item in omg:
  result = re.match(r'(.+)\\', item)
  if result in text:
   dada = dada + 1
   ddd[dada] = re.match(r'\\(.+)', item)
 ada = 0
 for item in ddd:
  ada = ada + 1
 txt = ddd[random.uniform(1, ada)]
 write_msg(user,txt,random.uniform(10300130, 20300130))
 return`

Comment: Нужно поправить мой код.

Comment: https://blast.hk/threads/39649/
Вот здесь код можно рассмотреть в более  нормальном виде

Comment: Пожалуйста, прикладывайте код не картинками, а текстом. Также - не надо прикладывать код вопроса в комментарии к вопросу или в ответ: его нужно прикладывать к вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

На будущее также присылайте код ошибки.

Ваша проблема в том, что вы записываете что-то в пустой массив(я уже молчу о том, что делаете это начиная с индекса 1)
Лучше воспользуйтесь методом `append()`:

```
ddd.append(re.match(r'\\(.+)', item))
```

Таким образом вы одновременно создаете новый индекс и заполняете его

Comment: Заменил на append, но у меня возникает ошибка при добавление каждой строчки документа в массив.

Comment: Ссылка на скриншот ошибки -https://imgur.com/a/hGuhlU6

Comment: Вот другой вариант этого же кода. Но всё равно какая-то ошибка при  прохождение по строчкам документа.
https://imgur.com/yjLLllH

Comment: Проблема в кодировке, попробуйте метод `.encode("utf-8")`

Comment: Можете скинуть пример, где это использовать и как?